# Least-square fit with uneven distribution of data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, python

I'd like to perform least-squares fit to data which is unevenly distributed on the x-axis.

For example, if I was to bin the data, it would be something like

x = 0~5: 10 data points

x = 5~10: 20 data points

x = 10~15: 2 data points

x = 15~20: 4 data points

I want to fit a best-fit to this to predict future values, but the model of course performs poorly for high values of x.

I can bin the data as above and then assign weights to the data based on the density (sparsity) of values in each bin. These weights can then be used to weight the contribution to the total error by each point, but I wonder: Is this the standard way of dealing with this problem, or is there another method?

Incidentally, I will be implementing this using a python library, so any advice about practical implementation is also appreciated.

Thank you for any advice!

Edit: Added a picture for illustration.

**Left**: Well-distributed points leading to a reasonable estimation for all x.

**Right**: Points distributed to lower-x values, leading to poor estimation of y at high-x values

[image: Left: Well-distributed points leading to a reasonable estimation for all x. Right: Points distributed to lower-x values, leading to poor estimation of y at high-x values]

Comment: The standard way is to use ordinary least squares with no weights at all.  In what sense does this "perform poorly" for the higher values of $x$?  (In fact, it will tend to fit those observed values *more closely* than it will fit the lower values.  But that does not mean more poorly.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Since there are more points at low x, the total error can be minimised by making the linear trend fit well at low x at the expense of high x, which only have a couple of points and therefore contribute only a little to the total error. If the data were truly linear then unweighted fitting in this case may be fine, but my data is not really linear. So perhaps rather than worrying about weighting, a better step would be to try fitting with a non-linear function?

Comment: Also, I wonder if you could clarify further what you mean by "it will tend to fit those [higher x] observed values more closely than it will fit the lower [x] values. But that does not mean more poorly."? (Sorry if this is an elementary question.)

Comment: Is X the dependent or independent variable?

Comment: x is independent. I've added a picture to make things clearer.

Comment: The situation actually is the opposite of what you think. Points far to the left or right have high *leverage*. The least squares fit will tend to go closer to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that some data is redundant simply because they are similar in value (on the x-axis) then your approach is correct (if ignoring issues of outliers).  The technique you are looking for is called [Kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).  The kernel bandwidth should be chosen based on the context of the data.  If x-values within a certain distance are to be considered redundant then the bandwidth of the kernel should be wide enough to include any two values within that distance.  Then you can use the inverse of the density estimation as the weights used in the least-squared regression.

Two dimensional kernel's can be used if two points can be considered non-redundant even though they have the same x-value.  (e.g. a single point in the top left of your graph would have the same weight as the values in the top right.)

Comment: KDE does *not* perform regression--even in 2D--so it's difficult to see how this post answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, I found [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-021-06023-5) to be of great interest.
For what I understood, there is usually 2 ways to deal with such non well distributed dataset :

- either we resample the dataset, usually by deleting some data to transform the dataset into a well distributed one,
- or we weight the data points, for example here by accounting for the density of points along x axis.

The second approach is the one they propose in the article. One advantage compared to the first method is that we do not delete data points so we can say in a way that we are more representative. They implement the method in a python package called [denseweight](https://github.com/SteiMi/denseweight). It is based on a kernel density estimation which allows you to get the weight for each point.

Then you can use a weighted linear regression with these weights, for example `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` with `sigma` parameter to account for the uncertainty of each data point. Setting `sigma=1/weights` will make isolated points more certain than dense groups of points according to their weight.

Here is an example with my dataset (x, y), either using `denseweight` module, or directly trying to use gaussian kernel density estimation:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from denseweight import DenseWeight
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

f = lambda x, a, b : a * x + b

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, '+')

# Standart linear regression :
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y)
xfit = np.array(ax.get_xlim())
yfit = popt[0] * xfit + popt[1]
ax.plot(xfit, yfit, '-', label='standard linear fit')

# Weighted linear regression with denseweight module' :
dw = DenseWeight(alpha=1)
weights = dw.fit(x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, sigma=1/weights)
yfit = popt[0] * xfit + popt[1]
ax.plot(xfit, yfit, '-', label='weighted linear fit with denseweight module')

# Weighted linear regression with gaussian_kde :
kde = gaussian_kde(x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, sigma=kde.pdf(x))
yfit = popt[0] * xfit + popt[1]
ax.plot(xfit, yfit, '-k', label='weighted linear fit with gaussian_kde')

ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to CV and thank you for the effort you put into posting a clear answer.  However, I find it difficult to compare two fits that are so obviously bad.  What would be the point of using any of the lines shown here to describe these data?  There is a real disconnect between performing any kind of regression and reweighting the explanatory variable, because they have completely different aims and regression is always *conditional* on the explanatory variable, which implies it doesn't need or use any weights or make distributional assumptions about that variable.

Comment: Thank you @whuber for your comment. My dataset represents a 2D space trajectory of a particle going from left to right in the above figure. The particle has an increasing velocity, but the points are recorded with a fix time step. And for the last time steps (right side of the figure) the particle is too poorly detected. This is why we have more points in the left side of the graph. I know from other observations that the real trajectory is quite linear. What I want is to recover the global slope of this linear trajectory which in fact is closest to the black/green curve than the red curve.

Comment: You seem to be saying you know the data are not what they are!  It is difficult to justify characterizing these (many) data points as "quite linear."

Comment: I know the global trajectory shape just by watching the recording images of the particle, that is why I can say that at the scale of the entire path the particle has taken, the trajectory is "quite linear".

Comment: It is common to have some datasets which have non well distributed data which makes simple regression to not be representative of the reality. I gave an example with my particle, but we could think of other cases, for example if you take a car accelerating in a roundabout, and you record the scene with a drone from the top with a fix frame rate, this will give you way more data points at the beginning of the trajectory where the car is slow enough than at the end of the trajectory where the car goes too fast. This leads to wrong estimation of the entire trajectory. How should we deal with it ?

Comment: How, precisely, does it lead to incorrect estimation of the trajectory?  It's easy to imagine many incorrect methods, but any correct method ought to do a good job without any kind of resampling or reweighting to accommodate the fixed frame rate.

Comment: That is the point here, we want to find a correct method which gives a good estimation (that is a circle trajectory around the roundabout). I proposed resampling or weighting. I don't say there are the only solution. What I understand is that you mean that those methods are not necessary and not the way to do it. But what do you propose ? How could I find the correct circle trajectory  with the non well distributed dataset ? A standard estimation would favor the trajectory of the car in the first meters because there are more data points there.

Comment: The solution depends on the nature of your data and your model.  Ideally you would know something about the distribution of measurement errors (isotropic?  independent? *etc.*) and you would posit a physically realistic but flexible family of solutions, such as all lines or all circles or all quadratics, depending on the need, along with a model for acceleration (and maybe its derivatives).  The rest usually is straightforward application of regression techniques.

Comment: Let's say the measurements are the most precise and accurate, so that we don't care about the distribution of measurement errors. The problem is still here and at least for me, "the straightforward application of regression techniques" is not so obvious and I think this is also the purpose of this thread. How to deal with uneven distribution of data, without favoring the part of the data where the points are the most concentrated, from a practical point of view for some simple physical applications ? Thank you for your previous answers.

Comment: My point is that the distribution of your data is irrelevant.  The explanatory variable, *time,* has a uniform distribution by design.  For regression (or curve fitting generally) what matters is the distribution of the *residuals,* not of the response.  Attempting to adjust the procedure according to the marginal response distribution will likely introduce bias and is unlikely to improve things.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cubic splines. One advantage of splines over standard polynomial regression is that data points influence is more local. This is due to irregularity at knots.